Geom_text object not found error/error in grid.call when trying to add labels to volcano plot
I am trying to add labels to the top differentially regulated genes in my volcano plot and keep getting an object not found error when I am pretty sure the object exists.
This is my initial code for the volcano plot which works fine:
# Loading relevant libraries 
library(tidyverse) 
library(RColorBrewer) 
library(ggrepel) 

# Import results
df <- read.csv(paste0('rnaseqstrdataclean.csv'), row.names = 1)
#Remove NA
dfnona <- na.omit(df)
# Add a column to the data frame to specify if they are UP- or DOWN- regulated
dfnona$diffexpressed <- "NO"
  # if log2Foldchange > 0.6 and pvalue < 0.05, set as "UP"
dfnona$diffexpressed[dfnona$log.Fc > 0.6 & dfnona$P.value < 0.05] <- "UP"
  # if log2Foldchange < -0.6 and pvalue < 0.05, set as "DOWN"
dfnona$diffexpressed[dfnona$log.Fc < -0.6 & dfnona$P.value < 0.05] <- "DOWN"

ggplot(data = dfnona, aes(x = log.Fc, y = -log10(P.value),color=diffexpressed)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = c(-0.6, 0.6), col = "gray", linetype = 'dashed') +
    geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "gray", linetype = 'dashed') + 
    geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red", "blue"),
                                      labels = c("Not significant", "Upregulated"))

After this, I made another dataframe with just the top 50 upregulated genes:
  
dfnona$delabel <- ifelse(dfnona$Name %in% head(dfnona[order(dfnona$P.value), "Name"], 50), dfnona$Name, NA)

dfnona2 <- na.omit(dfnona)

At this point, dfnona shows a column with either NA or the gene ID and dfnona2 shows only the top 50 genes.
When I try to add geom_text using dfnona2 though, it keeps giving an error that the Log.Fc object does not exist. When I view the dataframe, the Log.FC column is definitely still there. I tried a few different things based on past threads but it just keeps giving me the same error.

ggplot(data = dfnona, aes(x =log.Fc, y = -log10(P.value),color=diffexpressed)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-0.6, 0.6), col = "gray", linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "gray", linetype = 'dashed') + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red", "blue"),
                                    labels = c("Not significant", "Upregulated"))+
  geom_text(data =dfnona2,aes(x= log.FC,y=-log10(P.value), label = delabel, size = 4, colour = ""),  vjust = -1.2, hjust = "center")+
  geom_text_repel(max.overlaps = Inf)

I tried referring to just dfnona in geom_text but even then it also gives the same error that log.FC does not exist.  I tried including label=delabel in the aes for dfnona initially.
When I redo the code like this:
ggplot(data = dfnona, aes(x =log.Fc, y = -log10( P.value),color=diffexpressed)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(-0.6, 0.6), col = "gray", linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "gray", linetype = 'dashed') + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red", "blue"),
                                    labels = c("Not significant", "Upregulated"))+
  geom_text(aes(x= log.Fc,y=-log10( P.value),label = delabel, size = 4, colour = ""),  vjust = -1.2, hjust = "center")+
  geom_text_repel(max.overlaps = Inf, aes(x= log.Fc,y=-log10( P.value),label=delabel))

It gives me a different error:
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  :
Viewport has zero dimension(s).
Here is an example of the dataframe dfnona/dfnona2 looks like:
                   Chr                         Region          Name        MGM       Fc
ENSMUSG00000102123   1 complement(72146314..72161160)        Gm4319 0.05635501 5.011450
ENSMUSG00000026751   2 complement(38582668..38604554)         Nr5a1 0.47985910 9.848135
ENSMUSG00000115955   2           130365915..130369204 9530056E24Rik 0.06226478 3.623276

                     log.Fc      P.value       FDR Bonferroni diffexpressed       delabel
ENSMUSG00000102123 2.325228 0.0208974720 0.9999055          1            UP        Gm4319
ENSMUSG00000026751 3.299851 0.0000836434 0.9999055          1            UP         Nr5a1
ENSMUSG00000115955 1.857295 0.0199932020 0.9999055          1            UP 9530056E24Rik

Is there anyway I can fix this?

In your example that doesn't work, you have used log.FC instead of log.Fc. The column log.FC doesn't exist, since R is case-sensitive. Is it just a typo?

Oh my gosh, thank you, yes I had it as FC and didn't notice. I still get an error in grid.call though even after fixing it there.
